# Shutdown executor without executorService in Java

Tags: java, shutdown, executor

Is there a way to shutdown an `Executor` in Java without first casting it to `ExecutorService`? Basically i have a class called `Exx` that `implements Executor`. I want to shutdown Exx. How would I do that? Essentially,  I need to know how to shutdown an `Executor`.

EDIT: Example:

```
class Exx implements Executor{
    @Override
    public void execute(Runnable r) {
        new Thread(r).start();
    }       
}
```

Comment: Please include an [sscce](http://www.sscce.org) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: If the Exx class is not an ExecutorService, casting an instance of Exx to ExecutorService will obviously fail. If the class doesn't provide a way to shutdown instances, it means that it can't be shut down, or that it lacks such a method.

Comment: @JBNizet: I have edited to show example. How do I know each thread in the executor has stopped?

Comment: @user1467855 - you can't in the general case.  that is up to the executor itself to track.  in which case it can implement ExecutorService and you can use the extra management methods there.

Comment: Your class has nothing to shut down, since it doesn't even keep track of the threads it creates. Frankly, multi-threading is a very complex matter, and implementing Executors and ExecutorServices is a very advanced task. I don't think you should do that given your understanding of Java at this time. Use the standard executors that are provided by the API.

Answer (score 3):

An `Executor` by nature of the specific interface is not something that needs to be shutdown. For instance, here is the most basic implementation of `Executor`.

```
class NearlyPointlessExecutor implements Executor {
    public void execute(Runnable r) {
        r.run();
    }
}
```

Clearly in the code above, there is nothing so complicated that anything need be shutdown, yet the provided class adheres completely to the `Executor` interface.

If your implementation does need to be shutdown, then your options are either to make your own interface or implement `ExecutorService`.

**Update for question edit:**

In the case of the provided code, it would not be possible to shutdown the Threads being created because no reference to them is kept in a collection.

However, there is a solution, the implementation provided is essentially the same as the one provided by using: [Executors.newCachedThreadPool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool%28%29). Discard your own implementation and use this one instead.

Comment: I have edited to show example. How do I know each thread in the executor has stopped?

Comment: "my own" is actually a simplified version of what I need to do. I am overriding the Executor because ExecutorService has too many methods to override. And more importantly, I need to include costume methods to do other things. But I suppose I can always use ExecutorService and override it.